# Define outlet position with variable

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I try to define the x and y position of outlets with variables to realize a movement depending on the variable.

I have already tried different types of definitions and to define the variable as CGRECT but there was always the error:

`Value of type '(CGRect) -> CGRect' has no member 'origin'`

I've searched the internet and forums, but found nothing. It would be nice if you could help me with my request.

Thank you in advance!!

Relevant part of the CODE:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var axis = 0

class SensorPage: UIViewController, DownloadModelProtocol{

    @IBOutlet weak var out1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.animateControl), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func animateControl(){
        downloadModel.getbeladen(getvariable: "stuff")
        switch dItemA {
        case 0.0:
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.out1.frame.origin.x = axis
                self.out1.frame.origin.y = 340
            }, completion: nil)
        default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `axis` is not a CGFloat.

Comment: this code is working fine in my demo code, you did something wrong in your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define <em> axis </em> CGFloat.
var axis : CGFloat = 0.0
```

OR

```
self.out1.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(axis)
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking into using [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) rather than changing the views frame.

Long story short, you change the `transform` property rather than the `frame`.

There are many videos and blogs etc explaining the pros and cons about it.